# force jsf not decode code in html

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces, decode

I work on jsf 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3. Then in the java bean, I put a coded text in which I replace "é" with "& #233;" but when I inspect the element in the browser I find "amp;& #233;"
My question is how can I force jsf to not add "amp;" to code.

Comment: Don't put a space inbetween the & and the #.

Comment: thank you Mr Lister, in my code i don't put space. I put this space just to show the original expression and not its interpretation

Comment: Your question is _how can you force jsf not to add "amp;" to code_ OR how can you force jsf not to escape the symbol & ?

Comment: I want that jsf sends to browser the string value "& #233;" without adding "amp;"

Answer (score 1):

You  could set  escape attribute of outputtext, outputlabel, outputFormat to  false. 
 check this link  http://www.coderanch.com/t/569059/JSF/java/escape-false-outputText